# What was the state of the Hutt military?

Tags: star-wars, weapon

While reading about the [Hutt Cartel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hutt_Cartel) I read that the Cartel had an army and starship fleet:

> It maintained a personal military consisting of both an army and a starfleet.

This got me thinking, **What is the state of the Hutt military during the Galactic civil war?**

The only knowledge I have on this topic is that a number of Hutts employed [Gamorreans](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gamorrean/Legends) as guards, including Jabba, as seen during [*Return of the Jedi*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_VI_Return_of_the_Jedi) (and I assume that they were not pilots in the Hutt fleet due to their low intelligence.)

Can anyone give me insight into:

1. Who did they use as soldiers/pilots?
2. What Starships and weapons did they use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Calling Hutt Cartel forces a military would be a huge stretch**

Both in Canon and Legends, Hutts usually employed typical mercenaries (mafia "soldiers") with occasional combat droid, but these "troops" lacked uniformity, discipline and training to be called a military . This goes well with the nature of Hutt Cartel which was in its essence loose confederation of various crime lords, with some informal rules but real law was might and will of local Hutt and his henchmen.

As for their "fleet", Hutts did use plethora of ships, mostly converted transports but some where real warships like [Ajuur-class heavy cruiser](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ajuur-class_heavy_cruiser). Crews of those ships were also mercenaries from different species ([Weequay](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Weequay/Legends), [Devaronian](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Devaronian/Legends) etc ...)

In Legends, before Hutt Cartel there was [Hutt Empire](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hutt_Empire), more state-like organization which probably had proper military, but little is known about them.

Comment: Do you have any info on the small arms and ground vehicles that these _soldier mercenaries_ would have used?

Comment: @Boolean Nothing particularly interesting except maybe this http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bantha-II_cargo_skiff/Legends